# float precision in python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I want a floating point precision like `Fortran` in `python` program. In `Fortran` using `pi` gives a value of `3.141592653589793238462643` while using same `numpy.pi` gives a value of `3.141592653589793`. Is it possible to get floating point accuracy like `Fortran` in `python`? Tried `float128` but did not work. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) to create floats of an arbitrary precision:

```
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 25
mypi = (mp.quad(lambda x: mp.exp(-x**2), [-mp.inf, mp.inf]) ** 2)

print mypi   # 3.141592653589793238462643
```